# Diskpart will NOT open through cmd

Tags: cmd.exe, diskpart

I open up my cmd and type 'diskpart'  It prompts me with the UAC box, I click yes.  Everything is going good up until this point.  After I click 'Yes' diskpart opens up in a separate window (At school it opens up within the current cmd window, this might be where the problem lies) but instead of starting up I'm left with a blank cmd instance and diskpart will NOT open.  Any ideas?

Comment: Use USB boot flash disk)

Answer (score 2):

Couple things to try.  Right-Click Command Prompt and hit Run As Administrator.  When you type `diskpart` it will not spawn another command window.

Another thing to try would be to disable UAC.  You do that by going to Control Panel -> Action Center -> User Account Control.  Having UAC disabled mimics the behavior you are seeing at school (where things never prompt for elevation).

If neither of these things works, then you have a problem with diskpart or the storage management system on your computer.  If they do work, then your issue is some kind of problem with elevation which (hopefully) only affects this one scenario.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a disk that will not initialize at all (i.e. it's completely broken) then you will sit at the "On computer: yourpcname" screen forever. The disk is toast and will most likely need binning.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was stuck on  "On computer: yourpcname" screen forever as well. I had a bitlocker protected USB drive that was still locked. A few seconds after I unlocked it, the cmd session moved on to the diskpart> command prompt. Disk management wouldn't load either until I unlocked the bitlockered drive.